# How to request focus on Dialog OK button in Javafx?

Tags: javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

How to get Focus on OK button of a Dialog whenever Enter key is pressed on a TextField. I have tried the following code. But In give code, whenever the Enter Key is pressed on "city_D" (TextField), The OK button must get focused.

```
package dialogdemo;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ButtonBar;
import javafx.scene.control.ButtonType;
import javafx.scene.control.Dialog;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCode;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.Priority;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/**
 *
 * @author vikassingh
 */
public class DialogDemo extends Application {

    String street_1 = "";
    String street_2 = "";
    String city = "";

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Button btn = new Button();
        btn.setText("Say 'Hello World'");
        btn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                System.out.println("Hello World!");

                TextField street_1_D = new TextField();
                TextField street_2_D = new TextField();
                TextField city_D = new TextField();

                Dialog<List<String>> dialog = new Dialog<>();
                dialog.setTitle("Address");
                dialog.setHeaderText(null);
                dialog.setGraphic(null);

                // Set the button types.
                ButtonType okButtonType = new ButtonType("Ok", ButtonBar.ButtonData.OK_DONE);

                dialog.getDialogPane().getButtonTypes().addAll(okButtonType, ButtonType.CANCEL);
                dialog.getDialogPane().setStyle("-fx-background-color: #fff;");

                VBox box = new VBox();
                VBox.setVgrow(box, Priority.ALWAYS);

                box.getChildren().addAll(street_1_D, street_2_D, city_D);
                dialog.getDialogPane().setContent(box);

                // Request focus on the username field by default.
                Platform.runLater(() -> street_1_D.requestFocus());

                // Dialog All Listner
                street_1_D.setOnKeyPressed(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {
                    public void handle(KeyEvent event) {
                        if (event.getCode() == KeyCode.ENTER || event.getCode() == KeyCode.TAB || event.getCode() == KeyCode.DOWN) {
                            street_2_D.requestFocus();
                            event.consume();
                        }
                    }
                });
                street_2_D.setOnKeyPressed(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {
                    public void handle(KeyEvent event) {
                        if (event.getCode() == KeyCode.ENTER || event.getCode() == KeyCode.TAB || event.getCode() == KeyCode.DOWN) {
                            city_D.requestFocus();
                            event.consume();
                        }
                        if (event.getCode() == KeyCode.UP) {
                            street_1_D.requestFocus();
                            event.consume();
                        }
                    }
                });
                city_D.setOnKeyPressed(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {
                    public void handle(KeyEvent event) {
                        if (event.getCode() == KeyCode.ENTER || event.getCode() == KeyCode.TAB || event.getCode() == KeyCode.DOWN) {
                            //okButtonType.requestFocus();
                            event.consume();
                        }
                        if (event.getCode() == KeyCode.UP) {
                            street_2_D.requestFocus();
                            event.consume();
                        }
                    }
                });

                // END Dialog All Listner
                List<String> databaseFiles = new ArrayList<String>();
                dialog.setResultConverter(dialogButton -> {
                    if (dialogButton == okButtonType) {
                        street_1 = street_1_D.getText();
                        databaseFiles.add(street_1);
                        street_2 = street_2_D.getText();
                        databaseFiles.add(street_2);
                        city = city_D.getText();
                        databaseFiles.add(city);
                        return databaseFiles;
                    }
                    return null;
                });

                Optional<List<String>> result = dialog.showAndWait();
                if (result.isPresent()) {
                    System.out.println("Street 1: " + street_1 + " \n Street 2: " + street_2 + "\n City: " + city);
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Cancle");
                }
            }
        });

        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        root.getChildren().add(btn);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);

        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the button from the dialog pane and request the focus like this:

```
city_D.setOnKeyPressed(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {
    @Override
    public void handle(KeyEvent event) {
        if (event.getCode() == KeyCode.ENTER ||
            event.getCode() == KeyCode.TAB ||
            event.getCode() == KeyCode.DOWN) {

            dialog.getDialogPane().lookupButton(okButtonType).requestFocus();
            event.consume();
        }
        if (event.getCode() == KeyCode.UP) {
            street_2_D.requestFocus();
            event.consume();
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

First off, it doesn't sound like what you really want is "Focus" on the button.  To get the button to respond to "Enter" you need to make it the "Default" button.  The most obvious way to do that is to bind the DefaultButton property of the button to the Focused property of the city_D field.

However, you can also set OnAction on a TextField, which fires when you hit <Enter> on the textfield, which means that you can do whatever the OK button does without having an OK button.

Also, you can bind the DefaultButton property of the button to the Focused property of the Button.  Then it will fire when you hit "TAB" on the last field (passing the focus to the Button), and then "Enter".

Personally, I wouldn't mess around with the UP, DOWN and ENTER traversal stuff.  Most people are used to using TAB and SHIFT-TAB to move around screens, and the other stuff just clutters up the code for little value.  If you do want to do this, I'd consider using a TraversalEngine based solution.

But if you really want to use <Enter> to move to the next field, I'd use OnAction to do it.  Here's a sample that shows a mixture of all of this stuff:

```
public class sampleFrame2 extends Application {

class TestPane extends BorderPane {

    private Label label;
    private TextField tf1 = new TextField();
    private TextField tf2 = new TextField();
    private TextField tf3 = new TextField();
    private Button button1 = new Button("the button");
    private Text text = new Text("Not set");

    public TestPane() {
        VBox vbox = new VBox();
        vbox.getChildren().addAll(tf1, tf2, tf3, button1, text);
        tf1.setOnAction(evt -> tf2.requestFocus());
        tf2.setOnAction(evt -> tf3.requestFocus());
        tf3.setOnAction(evt -> text.setText("From tf3"));
        button1.setOnAction(evt -> text.setText("From button1"));
        button1.defaultButtonProperty().bind(button1.focusedProperty());

        setCenter(vbox);
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

    Pane root = new TestPane();
    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 250));
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

}